# How to Edit and Save ViewModels data back to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel which is joined by three Entities to get data from all entities into one view form. Although i succeeded to implement the same. But i have no idea how to Edit and Save data back to the database. My model classes are joined by one to one relationship.

My Models are:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speciality { get; set; }

    public virtual DoctorAddress DoctorAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual DoctorCharge DoctorCharge { get; set; }
    public virtual DoctorAvailablity DoctorAvailablity { get; set; }

}

public class DoctorAddress
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorCharge
{
    public decimal OPDCharge { get; set; }
    public decimal IPDCharge { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel is:

```
public class DoctorViewModel
    {
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public DoctorAddress DoctorAddress { get; set; }
        public DoctorCharge DoctorCharge { get; set; }

    }
```

My Controller is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = from t1 in db.Doctors
                    join d in db.DoctorAddress on t1.DoctorId equals  d.DoctorId into listi
                    join dc in db.DoctorCharges on t1.DoctorId equals dc.DoctorId into listj

                    from d in listi.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from dc in listj.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    select new DoctorDetailsViewModel.DoctorViewModel { Doctor = t1, DoctorAddress = d, DoctorCharge = dc };

        return View(model.ToList());

    }
```

My View is:

```
@model XXX.DoctorDetailsViewModel.DoctorViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Doctor</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
       Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Doctor.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        OPD Charge
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorCharge.OPDCharge)
    </div>

<div class="editor-label">
        Address
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.Address)
    </div> <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}
```

My Controller Class is:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Doctor/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Doctor doctor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(doctor);
    }
```

Please help me how do i do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've basically got it.  Your action method receiving the POST should receive the same type as the view model, i.e. `DoctorViewModel`.  The Model Binding of the MVC Framework will automatically map the input fields to the corresponding properties in the view model based on their names.

Comment: How can Doctor and DoctorCharge entities can have a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: @ataravati The Doctor class has a DoctorCharge property and vise versa.

Comment: @Jaan Did my comment help explain things or do you have any further questions?

Comment: For edition to work, you'll have to put your `DoctorId` in a hidden field, or you will end creating new Doctor each time you save. e.g. `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Doctor.DoctorId)`

Comment: No i am getting Error:

Comment: Error : The current request for action 'create' on controller type 'DoctorController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(HMS.Models.Doctor) on type HMS.Controllers.DoctorController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(HMS.ViewModels.DoctorDetailsViewModel) on type HMS.Controllers.DoctorController

Comment: @Jaan, you have asked 8 questions so far, had answers to 5 of them, and have not given feedback on a _single proposed answer_. Have no answers on any of your questions helped you so far?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's really good that you are using `ViewModels` but for this particular case, it's probably not necessary, your `Create` view could look like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Doctor

//other fields here

<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.Address)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorCharge.IPDCharge)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorCharge.IPDCharge)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorCharge.IPDCharge)
</div>

//other fields here
```

Then your `Doctor` controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Doctor doctor)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(doctor);
}

Your `Edit` action could then look like this:

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Doctor doctor = db.Doctors.Find(id);
    if (doctor == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(doctor);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Doctor doctor)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(doctor).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(doctor.DoctorAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(doctor.DoctorCharge).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(doctor);
}
```

If you want to keep your ViewModel then it could look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(DoctorViewModel doctorViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var doctorAddress = doctorViewModel.DoctorAddress;
        var doctorCharge = doctorViewModel.DoctorCharge;
        var doctor = doctorViewModel.Doctor;
        db.Entry(doctorAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(doctorCharge).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(doctor).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(doctor);
}
```

Comment: It's wise to use view models regardless - if only to negate the risk of accidentally exposing properties to modification later down the line

Answer (score 4):

Here, for creating:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DoctorViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Doctor.DoctorAddress = model.DoctorAddress;
        model.Doctor.DoctorCharge = model.DoctorCharge;
        db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(doctor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this answer I'm using *Tom Dykstra’s* Tutorial Guide on [Implementing Basic CRUD Functionality with the Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) in **ViewModel** context.

The tutorial uses [TryUpdateModel(TModel, String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel%60%601%28%60%600,System.String,System.String[]%29) method call to update a single `Student` model in `Edit` method.

```
     var studentToUpdate = db.Students.Find(id);

     if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
           new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" })) {
           //Save all changes made in this context to the underlying database 
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

`TryUpdateModel` method returns `true` if update was successful, otherwise it returns `false`. Above the first parameter for `TryUpdateModel` method call is the `Student` model (`studentToUpdate`). The 2nd parameter is a prefix for looking values in the value provider (empty string `""`). 3rd parameter is list of properties that are updated: `”LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate"`

> As a best practice to prevent [overposting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application#overpost), the fields that you want to
>   be updateable by the Edit page are whitelisted in the TryUpdateModel
>   parameters.

To make the above work for `DoctorViewModel`, the second parameter (prefix) needs to be used too. For example for `Doctor` model:

```
  Doctor doctorToUpdate = db.Doctors.Find(id);

  bool doctorUpdateSuccess = TryUpdateModel(doctorToUpdate, "Doctor", 
                                new string[] { "Name", "Speciality" });
```

The prefix `"Doctor"` is needed for `TryUpdateModel` method call, because when `DoctorViewModel` is used, it cannot find `Doctor` model’s parameters otherwise. For example the below  Watch window shows how the form values are shown in Visual Studio in debug mode for edit method:

[image]

in `Edit` view the code below:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Doctor.Name)
</div>
```

creates the following html:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Doctor_Name" 
     name="Doctor.Name" type="text" value="Foo"/>
</div>
```

Here’s code for `Edit` method for `DoctorViewModel`

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Doctor doctorToUpdate = db.Doctors.Find(id);
    if (doctorToUpdate == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    bool doctorUpdateSuccess = TryUpdateModel(doctorToUpdate, "Doctor", new string[] { "Name", "Speciality" });

    DoctorAddress doctorAddressToUpdate = doctorToUpdate.DoctorAddress;
    if (doctorAddressToUpdate == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    bool doctorAddressUpdateSuccess = TryUpdateModel(doctorAddressToUpdate, "DoctorAddress", new string[] { "Address" });

    DoctorCharge doctorChargeToUpdate = doctorToUpdate.DoctorCharge;
    if (doctorChargeToUpdate == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    bool doctorChargeUpdateSuccess = TryUpdateModel(doctorChargeToUpdate, "DoctorCharge", new string[] { "OPDCharge" });

    // if all models have been successfully updated
    // then save changes to database
    if (doctorUpdateSuccess &&
        doctorAddressUpdateSuccess &&
        doctorChargeUpdateSuccess)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    DoctorDetailsViewModel.DoctorViewModel viewModel = new DoctorDetailsViewModel.DoctorViewModel();
    viewModel.Doctor = doctorToUpdate;
    viewModel.DoctorAddress = doctorAddressToUpdate;
    viewModel.DoctorCharge = doctorChargeToUpdate;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

It’s also a good idea to add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application#overpost) attribute to the code to prevent [cross-site request forgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages).

**Update**

I also made some small changes to model classes by adding attributes. This enables models with relationship to be found more easily:

```
DoctorAddress doctorAddressToUpdate = doctorToUpdate.DoctorAddress;

DoctorCharge doctorChargeToUpdate = doctorToUpdate.DoctorCharge;
```

Therefore models below have `[Key]` or `[Key, ForeignKey("Doctor")]` attributes

```
public class Doctor
{
    [Key]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speciality { get; set; }

    public virtual DoctorAddress DoctorAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual DoctorCharge DoctorCharge { get; set; }
    public virtual DoctorAvailability DoctorAvailablity { get; set; }

}

public class DoctorAddress
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorCharge
{
    public decimal OPDCharge { get; set; }
    public decimal IPDCharge { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

Any feedback in relation ViewModel updates is welcomed. Recently I faced similar problem in my own project, and this was the approach I used to solve this issue. I guess there are alternative ways to handle this issue.