# How to update multiple models at the same time in ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update Two models at the same time.

Models:

1. Page
2. Fields

One page has multiple fields, I want them to update at the same time.

```
public class PageEditViewModel
{
    public Page mPage { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3>Fields</h3>
                                @foreach (var field in Model.ContentFields)
                                {
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => field.Id)

                                    switch (field.FieldType)
                                    {
                                        case "TextBox":

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">
                                                     @field.FieldName<span class="required"> * </span>

                                                </label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => field.Content , new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            </div>
                                            break;

                                        case "TextArea":
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">
                                                    @field.FieldName<span class="required"> * </span>
                                                </label>
                                                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => field.Content, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            </div>
                                            break;

                                        case "Image":
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">
                                                    @field.FieldName<span class="required"> * </span>
                                                </label>
                                                <input type="file" name="contentImage" id="cImage" class="form-control" accept="image/*" />
                                            </div>
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

And Controller:

```
public ActionResult Update(PageEditViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var page = _context.MenuPages.Single(s => s.Id == viewModel.mPage.Id);
        var contentFields = _context.ContentFields.Where(c => c.MenuPageId == page.Id);

        var viewM = new PageEditViewModel
        {
            DashboardHeading = "Edit a Page",
            mPage = page,
            ContentFields = contentFields
        };
        return View("EditPage", viewM);
    }


    var pageEdit = _context.MenuPages.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == viewModel.mPage.Id);

    pageEdit.Name = viewModel.mPage.Name;
    pageEdit.IsActive = viewModel.mPage.IsActive;
    pageEdit.IsShowInMenu = viewModel.mPage.IsShowInMenu;

    //            _context.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var field in viewModel.ContentFields)
    {
        var cfield = _context.ContentFields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == field.Id);

        cfield.Content = field.Content;

    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

When I Send the data from View to Controller, I get the data for Pages but Null for the Fields Model (Object Reference not set to an instance...).

I am looking forward to any guide from members here.

Thanks.

Comment: There's quite similar type of question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237945/how-to-edit-save-viewmodels-data-back-to-database

Comment: @GertArnold let me add some more code here.

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated the question, Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think Umesh answer is correct.
After changing your loop, how are you setting your Html.TextBoxFor, HiddenFor and so on?

It should be:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ContentFields[i].Id)
```

Comment: If you like, I have a post about this in my blog :)
http://debuxing.com/model-binding-to-a-list-of-objects/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aleem glad that you like it and that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace @foreach loop on view

```
 @foreach (var field in Model.ContentFields)
                            {
```

By for loop

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ContentFields.Count; i++)
            {
```

This will bind your list to model, while sending data to controller